# Duplicate data when using autoload scrolling Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem where when using autoload scrolling, sometimes, it will duplicate the data...

It should be: page 1=>{1,2,3}, page 2=>{4,5,6}, page 3=>{7,8,9}. But sometimes it will be like this: page 1=>{1,2,3}, page 2=>{4,5,6}, page 3=>{7,8,9,7,8,9}.

It this normal?

Here is my jquery code:-

```
var xi = 1;
var load = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(document).scroll(function (e,ui) {
            load = 0;
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

                load = 1;

                if ((load == 1) && (xi <= limit)) {

                $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                $.post('subCatContentMore.php',{desc:"<?php echo $banner; ?>",group_no: xi}, function(d){

                    $("#results").append(d);

                    //hide loading image
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                    load = 1;
                    xi++;
                });

                }


           }
        });
           load = 0;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it is because scroll event is called twice (I had the same problem).

I suggest that you add a condition:

```
if((load == 0) && ($(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())) {
```